# Winforms load animation

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, events

I've created some code in my `button1_Click` event that adds an animation to my WinForms application so it slides up from below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point p = new Point(500, 350);
    this.Location = p;

    for (; p.Y > 250; p.Y--) {
        this.Location = p;
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Question

I want my form to open with this animation, so I've tried moving my code to the `Form1_Load` event, but it doesn't work. It just loads without the animation.

How do I make this animation run when the form is initialized?

Comment: Use the Form.Shown event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your animation code to the `Form.Shown` event handler.  I would recommend to you still set the initial position in the `Form.Load` as to avoid a momentary flash of the form at its default position.